# I'm not electrified by the existence of the blanket [electrical] and [electricity] tags, let's remove them, or at least blacklist them

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup, tag-blacklist-request

Both these tags are typically used when the poster isn't intending to dig for an actually descriptive tag. Neither of these tags should be existing, as they apply to *every single question* on this network.

Both tags are indicative of a bad question:

- Average SE.EE question score: [2.56](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/1168425/average-question-score-site-wide)
- Average [electricity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) question score: [1.17](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/1245891/average-tag-statistics-with-answers?tagname=electricity)
- Average [electrical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) question score: [0.60](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/1245891/average-tag-statistics-with-answers?tagname=electrical) (!)

I don't mean to imply the tag makes the question bad, but tagging something with [electrical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) is a pretty clear indication that the question hasn't seen the required amount of TLE, and the site would, in my humble opinion, be better off if we enforced not tagging with this pseudo-tag.

Comment: I did my best to add a play on words into the title, as is the requirement for any good tag-deletion/burnination question, at least on StackOverflow. Please don't PUNish me if it's not up to standards.

Comment: Electrocution would be a fitting end for those tags

Comment: But, but... almost all of my EE questions involve electricity!  :)

Comment: I was thinking about that the other day. It is pretty ridiculous that those tags exist. It's almost like if the Physics SE had a `science` tag or if Stack Overflow had a `code` tag LOL.

Comment: Soemone has added "status review" tag so it should automagically be being escalated.

Comment: There is also the [tag:electric] tag.

Comment: @Lundin: electrical electricity or electronical electricity?

Comment: This is in the CM team backlog, and we'll get back to you when we have updates.

Comment: @JNat um, I feel bad for asking/pointing this out, but these two tags aren't blacklisted for use, so there's new daily additions, what's the state of this?

Comment: I still don't have a date for you, @MarcusMüller, and will update y'all as soon as I have it. The CM team is working on [this initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353982/208518) currently, and I'll see if I can squeeze this in this week (no promises, though!).

Comment: @JNat no pressure! The question was more whether we can simply blacklist the tag *now* so that we have less to care about later.

Comment: This issue is now in Dev and will be worked on as a part of that queue.

Comment: @JuanM thank you, that's good news!

Answer (score 10):

I agree with you, but as I'm currently the only "active" mod (not active, really), I'll leave it open to collect some votes at least. And I hope that fresh new mod(s) will be willing to work on these issues, too.

Answer (score 10):

These tags look like a candidate for [intrinsic tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181772/enable-the-intrinsic-sitename-tag-blacklist-on-older-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Intrinsic tags are

> term[s] that can apply to *all* questions on the site [...]

Hopefully, this meta post can also function as a formal request to the Community Manager to blacklist them, as it is also stated,

> post a request on your meta and we'll mark it as intrinsic.

(a moderator may need to edit and add [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) to this question, as per [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/241919))

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of the mod tools, but I believe mods nowadays are able to "burninate" tags without involving CMs. Some mods over at SO have been very active in tag clean-up in the past few years. At any rate, widely used tags like these at least need moderator support to get rid of.

Comment: @Lundin you're correct that burninating can be done by community and mods, but blacklisting need CM. I made an edit to make it more clear it's about blacklist.

Answer (score 4):

These tags are intrinsic, they need to go away

Answer (score 2):

In general, all adjective-only tags are bad: they change the meaning depending on which noun they are applied to. "Electrical" is obviously meaningless without a noun, or at best equivalent to "Electricity".

"Electricity" is essentially a negative tag - it can be applied to any electromagnetic phenomenon in which the magnetic part is insignificant. This is also not useful, similarly to a "non-java" tag on Stack Overflow or "non-windows" tag on Super User.

Comment: Would something like "electrical-field" be more suitable for questions where the magnetic part is insignificant? And btw I now also found the "field" tag... for all our farming questions.

Answer (score 2):

These tags are now blocked

> two intrinsic tags
> now added to the blocklist
> electrocution!