# Let's not over-engineer questions: blacklist [engineering]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-blacklist-request

While cleaning up [electric](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric), I noticed that there are an [engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering) tag. On a website whose title is "Electrical Engineering", that's a strong candidate for an *intrinsic* tag, i.e., one that carries no information, because *every* question could carry it.

Current state is 116 questions, of which 20 are currently closed, non-deleted. That's not a great quota, and is as it seems a result of that tag to have a high likelihood to be used when people actually ask off-topic, non-technical questions.

So: let's blacklist that tag!

Comment: Your post is tagged "discussion". I suggest that that tag may also be intrinsic in meta :-)

Comment: I do agree, but there's a site mechanic that forces me to engineer that tag ;-)

Comment: Obviously all questions on the site should be tagged [tag:electric] [tag:engineering] :) Other gems are [tag:ground], [tag:power] (not to be confused with power-supply), [tag:voltage], [tag:current].

Comment: @Lundin I can see some need and specificity in [tag:ground], for example. Not every EE question is about ground! If I ask about a PCB layout with separate ground planes and how to connect them, for example, that would be a specific tag to use. I already successfully removed all [tag:electric] ([here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9930)), and we successfully removed users' abilities to use [tag:electrical] and [tag:electricity] ([here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7212)) on new questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is another intrinsic tag which needs to be blocklisted. As with "electric", at least some of the time it is only used when a user is trying to tag the question as "electrical engineering", which results in tagging the question with not just one intrinsic tag ("electrical-engineering") but two ("electrical" and "engineering").

I've removed it from all questions for which it is the only tag so that it can be "burninated" (i.e. deleted from all questions) without leaving any question untagged.

Comment: Hello, CM checking in on this, apologies for the delay in processing. Is the plan to remove [tag:engineering] from the 43 questions where it's used?

Comment: @Berthold Yes, please.

Comment: This has been completed. The block is set with the message "This term can be applied to all questions on the site." and the tag was removed from the remaining questions where it was used.